# How can I convert an associative array to JSON and send it as part of a POST request using ASP.NET?

Tags: php, asp.net, json, post

I'm writing some sample code fragments for a REST API that's developed in PHP and while I can manage to get a "Ruby" example, I haven't been able to find a decent ASP.NET (figures) example that would be equivalent.  I was wondering if any ASPer could help out with a nitty-gritty translation of the following PHP which issues a POST request with a JSON string as its payload.

The main thing to note is that the POST requires one named parameter "data" which is a JSON string.

```
    $key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';    // This would be your customer key
    $map='USA';
    $accountid='000';                                   // this would be your account id
    // add some zips to an array
    $zips[]=22201;
    $zips[]=90210;
    $zips[]=10001;

    // We encode an array into JSON
    $data = array("map" => $map, "zips"=>$zips, "accountid" => $accountid, "custkey" => $key);                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                       
    // IMPORTANT - the API takes only one POST parameter - data 
    $postdata="data=$data_string";

    // we use curl here, but Zend has Rest interfaces as well...
    $ch = curl_init('https://www.example.com//test/');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);         // make sure we submit a POST!

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
      $result=curl_error($ch);
    } else {
      curl_close($ch);
    }

    $jsonObj=json_decode($result);
    if($jsonObj->success){
      $coordinates=$jsonObj->coordinates;               
      foreach($coordinates->coordinates as $coord){
        //... application logic here ( construct XML for the map )
      }
    }
```

Thanks for the help - I hate posting stuff like this, but maybe it'll help someone else in the future as well!

R

In response to commments - my real request for help arises out of the lack of an ASP environment to debug/test an example.  For example - @Chris posted a link, and while translating it at face value seems trivial (attempt below), my problem is I'm not just sending data in the normal POST fashion:

```
param=val&param2=val2
```

It needs to go like:

```
data={JSONString}
```

where the JSONString is made from an associative array. Then the problem arises with associative arrays in ASP (or rather apparent lack thereof? --  http://blog.cloudspotting.co.uk/2010/03/26/associative-arrays-in-asp-net/) in general and then how to encode a non-existent associative array into a JSON string or if I try to use NamedValueCollection instead?  It also appears that JSON support in ASP is spotty, so I'm sure there is going to be a need for a special interface?

```
using System.Web;

Uri address = new Uri("http://www.example.com/test/");
// Create the web request
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
// Set type to POST
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
string map = "USA";
string accountid = "000";
string data =""; 
NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
data.Add("custkey", key);
data.Add("map", map);
data.Add("accountid", accountid);
```

How can I convert data to JSON since ASP doesn't actually have associative arrays?

```
string jsondata="";



StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
```

Does the line below break things when using UrlEncoding?

```
data.Append("data=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(jsondata));

// Create a byte array of the data we want to send
byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());

// Set the content length in the request headers
request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

// Write data
using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
  postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
}
// Get response
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
   // Get the response stream
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
   // Console application output
   string jsonResponse =reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

So I guess my question should be given the above hacked example - can someone tell me if this is correct or assist otherwise?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/post/3384091.aspx - 5 seconds in Google.

Comment: @ChrisL I think the OP was pretty polite in the way he posted this (despite the lack of effort).  There's no need to be rude.

Comment: Hi Ross! Requests for code translation don't really work well for the scope of Stack Overflow. If you have attempted the translation yourself, and have a specific question about where you've gotten stuck, that would be an appropriate thing to ask a question about. Right now, this is too broad, probably would not be helpful to future visitors, and shows kind of a lack of effort (note that I'm not saying you *haven't* tried anything, I'm just saying that's what it looks like).

Comment: Thanks @jadarnel27 - I understand - it wasn't that I hadn't tried something, but rather couldn't really "try" anything due to a lack of an ASP environment.  I'd encountered numerous examples as Chris provided, but the issue arose surrounding the associative array snarliness in ASP and then goes downhill from there at which point I figured and ASP vet could jam out something quickly to help me out.  We'll see if the elaboration above illicits more than just downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried jSon.Net? http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx Example:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
```

Combined with [this tool](http://json2csharp.com/) I find it is the best .Net/JSon combination out there.